# Designing a Database Schema - Data that is common to all users or custom made

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

Hi I am working on a calendar application using Ruby on Rails. Rails is database agnostic, so in development I'm using SQLite but in production I am looking to use PostgreSQL.The current obstacle that I am facing is with the way I am designing my database schema.

First I have a users table that holds information such as login info and email. Each user has_many plans.

Then I have a plans table that belongs_to users and each plan has an event it references, the date, start time, and end time.

So the plan tables would reference the events table.

Here is my issue:

I would like to have two event tables. One is custom events. The other is default events.
The default events is just a list of common events already defined so the user can already select from a list. The custom events table is a list of events created by a user that references their id.

Here is my solution:

Would it be sufficient to add a new boolean column to the plans table called "custom". And if it is true then the event_id (in plans table) will reference the custom events table, and if it is false then it will reference the default events table. Is this a valid solution and if so, how would I implement it into my Rails application?

Thank you for taking your time to read my question. I am sorry I am an idiot. I am practicing everyday to be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to not think in terms of tables first, but in terms of classes and the behavior of their instances. What would matter most in the end is not how many tables your design has, but whether the responsibilities have been correctly attributed to the different classes in your model.

In this case it looks like you need two different classes, because some events will belong_to a user and other won't. The former will be created, modified and deleted by that user, and the latter will be managed by an admin. The instances of those classes can be stored in the same table using STI (Single Table Inheritance), with a string column named 'type' to enable Rails to store the class for each instance. The UserEvent class will belong_to :user, and the DefaultEvent won't. Both classes can extend Event, which in turn extends ActiveRecord::Base.

Please let me know if you need additional clarification.

Comment: It's perfect! Thank you so much for answering my question. I love you.

Comment: If you choose to accept this answer to your question, you can indicate this by marking the check next to the answer.  This option is only available to the one who asked the question.  Marking accepted answers as such will help the community, and the one who provided the answer.